# How can I get JavaScript to 'unroll' a variable number of parameters?

Tags: javascript

For example suppose I have the following two functions

```
function a(param1) {
    console.log(param1);
}

function b(func, params) {
    func(params);
}
```

then

```
b(a, 1);
```

prints '1' as expected

Now suppose I have an additional function

```
function c(param1, param2) {
    console.log(param1, param2);
}
```

Is there some way of doing something similar to

```
b(a, 1);
```

Except feeding in two parameters?  Something like the following

```
b(c, [2, 3]);
```

Where the [2, 3] arrray is unrolled into individual parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function b(func) {
    func.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `apply` method of functions. So inside `b`, use `func.apply(this, params)` rather than just `func(params)`.

The first argument to `apply` is what to set `this` to; the second argument is an array of the arguments to pass to the function.

So something like `b.foo(1,2,3)` is the same as `foo.apply(b, [1,2,3])` assuming `b.foo = foo`.